# How to choose contour for rational approximation

Tags: cv.complex-variables, approximation-theory, potential-theory, interpolation

Let $f$ be an analytic function on $\Omega \subset \mathbb{C}$. The Hermite formula for interpolation at the points $a_k$, $k=1,\ldots,n$, using a rational function $r_n$ with poles at $b_k$, $k=1,\ldots,n$,
$$
        f(z) - r_n(z) 
        =
        \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_{\partial \Omega} \frac{\ell_n(z)}{\ell_n(w)} \, \frac{f(w)}{w-z} \, dw
, \qquad
\ell_n(z) = \frac{\prod_{k = 1}^n (z-a_k)}{\prod_{k=1}^n (z-b_k)}
,
$$
allows to estimate the interpolation error on a compact set $A\subset\Omega$ by 
$$
        \|f - r_n\|_{\infty,A}
        \leq
        \|f\|_{\infty,A} \, \frac{\sup_{z \in A} |\ell_n(z)|}{\inf_{w \in \partial\Omega} |\ell_n(w)|}
.
$$
We can then use logarithmic potential theory to find $a_k$ and $b_k$ which asymptotically minimise this expression, see e.g. chapter VIII in Saff & Totik "Logarithmic Potentials with External Fields". Thus, there is a complete theory on how to do asymptotically optimal rational interpolation except that I have to a-priori choose the domain of analyticity $\Omega$ or equivalently the contour $\partial \Omega$. Are there any guidelines/theory on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If the points $\{a_{k}\}_{k=1}^{n}\subset A$ and $\{b_{k}\}_{k=1}^{n}\subset\mathbb C\setminus\Omega$ are chosen as rational Fekete points (see p.396 of the reference mentioned by the OP), then it can be proved (see p.397) that
$$\limsup_{n\infty}\left(\frac{\sup_{z\in A}|l(z)|}{\inf_{z\in\mathbb C\setminus\Omega}|l(z)|}\right)^{1/n}\leq e^{-1/\text{cap}(A,\mathbb C\setminus\Omega)},$$
where $\text{cap}(A,\mathbb C\setminus\Omega)$ denotes the capacity of the condenser made of the two plates $A$ and $\mathbb C\setminus\Omega$, which is defined as the inverse of
$$\inf_{\mu_{1},\mu_{2}}\iint\log\frac{1}{|z-t|}d(\mu_{1}-\mu_{2})(z)d(\mu_{1}-\mu_{2})(t),$$
where $\mu_{1}$ and $\mu_{2}$ are probability measures supported on $A$ and 
$\mathbb C\setminus\Omega$ respectively. Note that if one of the sets becomes smaller, the infimum increases and the capacity decreases.

In order to optimize the rate of approximation, one thus has to minimize the capacity, or equivalently to choose $\Omega$ as large as possible. Hence the best rate of approximation is achieved when choosing $\Omega$ as the (maximal) domain of analyticity of the function $f$ and the contour as the boundary of this domain.

---

To answer the question in the comment about rational approximation to the function $1/(1+\exp(x))$ on the interval $[-1,1]$, here are the plots of the error functions of best (minimax) rational approximants of degrees 3 and 5, as computed by the Remez command of the Chebfun package.
[image]

Comment: Is it true though that $\text{cap}(A,\mathbb{C}\setminus\Omega) \geq \text{cap}(A,\mathbb{C}\setminus\Omega')$ for $\Omega \subset\Omega'$? I couldn't find such a statement in Saff's & Totik's book, and I actually doubt it. For a meromorphic function, that would mean the asymptotically best rational approximation is the one with poles in the poles of the function, but usually I can do better by clustering poles which are far away from $A$.

Comment: Also, the $\leq$ in your bound should be a $\geq$, right?

Comment: Concerning your first question, see my edited answer. For the notion of a condenser and its capacity, both sets should be of positive capacities, which is not the case for the set of polar singularities of a meromorphic function, but in order to achieve good approximation, one should certainly choose the poles of the approximants among the singularities of the function. Finally, the first inequality in my answer is correct as it stands.

Comment: You are right about the inequality, I confused it with inequality (3.2) from the book. Together they should imply that actually equality holds, right?

Comment: I'm still confused about the other part. I agree with your infimum argument, but I can't find where my statement about approximation of meromorphic functions goes wrong. Ok, the poles are a set of zero capacity, but I could choose small circles around the poles and I would end up in essentially the same situation. I'm particularly interested in approximation of the Fermi-Dirac function $f(z) = 1/(1+ \exp(z))$, which has equispaced simple poles along the imaginary axis. Then the maximal domain of analyticity is the complex plain without those poles.

Comment: Yes, together with (3.2) of the book, one gets equality in the limit.

Comment: For the other part, one should specify on which set $A$ the approximation needs to be performed.

Comment: Let's say $A = [-1,1]$.

Comment: The Remez algorithm as implemented in the Chebfun package gives the following errors for rational approximants of degrees 3, 4, 5, 6 :

3.4336e-08, 
3.4060e-11, 
2.1649e-14, 
4.4409e-16.